# spring mvc - @ResponseBody and produces based on browser?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is there any simple way to return a different content-type based on browser?

I'm hitting walls with IE when it comes down to application/json . most of times it works, other times not. 
I'd like to *always* return json object (through MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter) but to set content type to text/plain when using the IE.

writing to response.setContentType is not effective cause I have lots of controllers and extending the converter will also not help a lot since I don't have the request headers..

any ideas?

Comment: ie handles application/json just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to get the `User-agent` header from the HTTP request by using `@RequestHeader("User-Agent")` and then set the content type into an `HttpServletResponse` object which will be automatically set by Spring framework. Here is the example

```
@Controller
public class FoobarController {

    @RequestMapping("/path")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getContent(@RequestHeader("User-Agent") String userAgent,
                             HttpServletResponse response) {
        if (isIE(userAgent)) {
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
        } else {
            response.setContentType("text/json");
        }
        ...
        return "{\"key\":\"value\"}";
    }
}
```

And here is part of the User-Agent headers of IE,

- Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0)
- Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0)
- Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)

You can click [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/) to see more.

Comment: Thanks. we ended up doing something similar. extending MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter and return text/plain on IE header. so far tested in production for 2 weeks and works good.